# How to limit formatting of navigation menu to just the main menu and NOT to the items in the drop-downs. HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

Hi, if you look at the above screenshot you can see I have added in code to make a small bar transition across when hovering over items in the navigation bar.

However, this bar also appears when I hover over items in the drop down menu. For example, when hovering over "Stock 1" the bar appears and obviously looks awful.

How can I make it so that this bar only appears on the items in the main menu and NOT in the drop down menu's.

**Please see HTML code below:**

```
<header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/japan_flag.gif" alt="" height="31" width="41">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <nav role="navigation">
                <ul class="mainmenu">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Stock</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                      <li><a href="#">Stock 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Stock 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Enquiries</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="mobile-menu-wrap"></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**Please see CSS below:**

```css
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
}
  
nav {
    font-family: monospace;
}
  
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 45%;
}
  
nav ul li {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
    
nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
}
  
nav ul li a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color:  rgb(199, 50, 13);
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
  
nav ul li ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    background: rgb(199, 50, 13);
    opacity: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 9% 9%;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 10px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
  
nav ul li:hover > ul,
nav ul li ul:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}

nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    color: black;
}
  
nav ul li ul li {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul li a::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(199, 50, 13);

    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0%;
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav ul li a:hover::after {
    width:100%;
}
```

**Any help with this would be hugely appreciated as I have tried for ages to research and figure this out. I am very new to HTML, CSS and any sort of coding in general so apologies.**

Comment: You really need to learn about CSS selectors. One of the main purposes of those is using CSS to distinguish between the various html elements in your document and modify their properties (like font,color,size,behaviour,etc). This is basic CSS knowlegde. Here is a point to start from: [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give class to `<a>` on which you want to apply style..
You can do like this.

```
<header>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/japan_flag.gif" alt="" height="31" width="41">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <nav role="navigation">
            <ul class="mainmenu">
              <li><a class="abc" href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a class="abc" href="#">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a class="abc" href="#">Stock</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li><a href="#">Stock 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Stock 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Enquiries</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="mobile-menu-wrap"></div>
</div>
```

And in css file you can do like this:

```
.abc:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    color:  rgb(199, 50, 13);
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Seems obvious in hindsight but thanks so much for the detailed help!